# Terms in a specific context. Are they proper nouns and/or technical terms?

Tags: nouns, technical

Currently I am writing a report where I explain some basic concepts for developing plug-ins in Moodle. During this I am a bit struggling about the using of typical Moodle terms.

Moodle has, for example, terms like "Activity", "Resource", "Context", "Block" and I am unsure if they are proper nouns and if I should capitalize them?

Furthermore I am questioning if they are a technical term or are they common? (I mean "Resource" in general is common, but in Moodle it is more a "Moodle resource" so it is more technical or not?)

If I look at the documentation, for example [Resources](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Resources), more or less everything is not capitalized. However, in [Activities](https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Activities), they are...

Any suggestions or opinions?

Comment: In technical documents where I use regular words for specific meaning, I *italicize* them. A block may just be a shape. or it's a *block* as a reserved word. If the material becomes crowded with Italics, I'd use it the first time only, to show it's a special meaning word, then normal type.

Comment: Capitalization is your choice, not a rule. If it makes your text clearer, maybe you can use it.  [I'm struggling about using typical Moodle terms.]

Comment: @YosefBaskin I like your idea! In some rare cases they invented terms completely new. Would it make sense in this cases to capitalize them AND italic them at the first time or is that too much?

Comment: Yes, professionals don't want to look like they can't make the executive decision of italics or Caps. Amateurish move. I use caps for titles.

Comment: The documentation should be your reference for usage. If it isn't consistent, then there is no right and wrong thing, and do what seems best to you.